# How to find svg rectangle Absolute positioning while moving from one location to another

Tags: svg

Default rectangle position is (100,200) when it moved, how to get the absolute positioning based on SVG width and height.

Below code is giving relative path. When I move towards left/up it giving -ve values.

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
<!-- code  -->
<rect class="draggable" x="100" y="200" width="80" height="80" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I found this way.

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
<!-- code  -->
<rect class="draggable" width="80" height="80" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>
</svg>
```

In the above code I removed the x and y positions so that it's completely dependent on transform matrix e,f absolute positions.